# Get officeLocation from users within organization

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently trying to get the officeLocation field for users within our organization using the MS graph api. I'm using the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/email@domain.com?$select=department,displayName,jobTitle,mail,officeLocation,usageLocation
```

However, officeLocation is coming back as null. Looking at the documentation, it seems as though I need the Read.All permission which is an admin level permission. Is there know other way to get the users office location without an admin permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've requested the [`User.ReadBasic.All`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions) scope. This will only provide your app access to a limited set of basic profile properties (`displayName`, `givenName`, `surname`, `mail`, `photo`, and `extensions`). As you've found, `officeLocation` is not included in the basic profile property set.

In order to retrieve `officeLocation` you'll need a minimum of `User.Read.All` permission. As you noted, this requires that your application recieve [Admin Consent](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) before a normal user can consent to it themselves.

As a general rule of thumb, access to "other user's data" (any user other than the one who authenticated) requires a Tenant Admin to give their consent.

Comment: One more question after reading the article you linked to for admin consent. It says the link is generally one an admin follows. So is it good / normal practice just to give the URL directly to the admin, or have a flow in the app that handles this?I don't see having this in the app since it's a one time thing.

Comment: It depends on the app. Most folks provide it to the Admin as part of their onboarding/deployment process since that is often handled by an IT dept. For smaller/native apps that the user is installing directly, most just include the link in the Help with some basic instructions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for your prompt response, you've been of great help! Great articles as well!